# How do I force a user to either register or login before their post is saved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have a `Post` model, and anyone can create a post. But before it is saved, the user must be logged in.

I am using Devise. How do I force them to login/register before it is saved, and then just complete the operation once they do that?

I was initially thinking of doing a `before_save` on my `Post` model. The issue with that approach is that I don't have access to the `current_user` object in my model.

I am also unsure about how to save the record, and just continue the operation once they successfully login.

**Edit 1**

Another hacky way to do this is to simply change my `f.submit` to be a regular button that redirects them to the login page. The issue with that approach is that it doesn't save their info and allow them to just hit "submit" upon successful login. They have to go through the entire `post/_form` again - which is what I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like all problems could be avoided if you forbid people to access post-creating if they aren't logged in. If there are no cases where a user can create a post without being logged in, then make them log in first.
One way to do that would be to make the link that leads to post-creating (if there is such a thing) check if the user is logged in, and if they aren't send them to login form.

Comment: Well...it really is a funnel optimization issue. i.e. allowing people to begin the post creation process, they are much more likely to create a post than if they were automatically hit with a login screen. The abandonment rate is much higher than if they were already invested having entered the information.

Comment: This is really bad practice and UX issue, don't go that way. Any user musn't have permission to create any resource if he has to log in or create an account later. Why? Because it's really annoying and yet, user may doesn't know that he need to log in after writing a post.